# How to debug and view HTML ans CSS source code for Android default browser?

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, browser

I always have issue with the CSS styling in the default Android browser while building my responsive website. What I usually do was doing trials and errors on pc until the problem was solved.

There is a tool for chrome browser:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

but chrome usually display fine for me just that I need a debugging tool for the default Android browser. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: **It's pain in the a$$**, even Google understood it, thus Chrome is the default browser  for **Android KitKat** onwards. Please refer http://slides.com/html5test/the-android-browser#/ for more insights about android browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to test on the old android browser using remote debugging, as new devices nowadays (Anything post 4.0) have chrome installed by default on Android.

One method you can use to help with testing responsive/mobile sites is using [Chrome's mobile emulation tool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode)

Either select a device on that list, or fake out the user agent with something from this page http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Android%20Webkit%20Browser/